# json api parse object

Tags: javascript, json

Good day, I'm trying to get certain values ​​​​with api the maximum that I can do is output all the json

```
  const api_url = 'https://api.battlemetrics.com/servers/3753675'
  async function getData() {
    const response = await fetch(api_url);
    const json = await response.json();
    const { data } = json;
    console.log(data)
  }
  getData();
```

please could tell me how to get the element, I tried like this:

```
  const api_url = 'https://api.battlemetrics.com/servers/3753675'
  async function getData() {
    const response = await fetch(api_url);
    const json = await response.json();
    const { name, id, status } = json;
    console.log(name, id, status)
  }
  getData();
```

but i get "undefined undefined undefined"

The object I asked for:

```
{"data":{"type":"server","id":"3753675","attributes":{"id":"3753675","name":"Rusticated.com Sandbox - Creative | Minigames | Bedwars\r","address":null,"ip":"199.231.233.240","port":28015,"players":201,"maxPlayers":1000,"rank":1,"location":[-87.618889,41.875744],"status":"online","details":{"official":false,"rust_type":"modded","map":"BuildBattleArenaScrimGames","environment":"w","rust_ent_cnt_i":0,"rust_fps":43680,"rust_fps_avg":43680,"rust_gc_cl":null,"rust_gc_mb":null,"rust_hash":"","rust_headerimage":"https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/811789078105554984/832668733184671754/Rusticated_Mini_Games_Banner_512x256.png","rust_mem_pv":null,"rust_mem_ws":null,"pve":false,"rust_uptime":null,"rust_url":"https://rustminigames.com","rust_world_seed":1337,"rust_world_size":null,"rust_description":"Rusticated Minigames Beta \n Bedwars \n Creative \n GunGame \n Targets \n More Coming Soon...","rust_modded":true,"rust_queued_players":0,"rust_born":"2022-06-05T00:00:00.000Z","rust_last_ent_drop":"2021-08-06T00:10:18.261Z","rust_last_seed_change":"2020-09-03T18:33:52.047Z","rust_last_wipe":"2021-08-06T00:10:18.261Z","rust_last_wipe_ent":29035,"serverSteamId":"90159726978107400"},"private":false,"createdAt":"2019-06-18T18:35:26.890Z","updatedAt":"2022-06-06T10:05:57.516Z","portQuery":28038,"country":"US","queryStatus":"valid"},"relationships":{"game":{"data":{"type":"game","id":"rust"}}}},"included":[]}
```

Comment: The name, id and status are inside attribute object, did you tried accessing using attribute.name or id or status?

Comment: `name`, `id` and `status` are not top-level properties of the data structure. **You can't just ignore whole layers of the data structure!**

Comment: Try accessing like this
`json.data.attributes.status`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just need to replace:
`const { name, id, status } = json;`
with:

```
  const {
    data: {
      id,
      attributes: { name, status }
    }
  } = json;
```

because your keys are not directly into the response, but nested.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get object you said, try this.

```js
const API_URL = 'https://api.battlemetrics.com/servers/3753675';

async function getData() {
  const response = await fetch(API_URL);
  const json = await response.json();
  console.log(json);  // you need to check json first. (*)
}

getData();
```

Then you can use destructuring.

```js
const API_URL = 'https://api.battlemetrics.com/servers/3753675';

async function getData() {
  const response = await fetch(API_URL);
  const json = await response.json();
  const { name, id, status } = json.data.attributes; // (*)
  console.log(name, id, status);
}

getData();
```